# Яндекс карты для андроид приложения

Tags: android, яндекс-карты

Планируется разработка приложения на ОС Андроид, для учебного процесса (что то вроде своей ГИД-ГИС), которая должна будет включать:

1. Определение местоположения
2. На карте можно будет разместить POI
3. К этим точкам проложить маршрут

Пока понятия не имею, как это реализовать, просто надо знать, возможно ли это? и бесплатно ли?

И еще вопрос. Возможно ли скачать яндекс-карты и использовать их оффлайн?

Comment: Обязательно использовать карты яндекса?
я давно ими не интересовался, но раньше там не было возможности построения маршрута. 
на картах google вы точно сможете сделать все, что вам нужно.

Comment: Дело в том, что в Гугле не прорисован наш город вообще.

Comment: как тогда на счет openstreetmaps?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Возможно.
Бесплатно.

Comment: с яндекс-картами?

Comment: я ответил на первые два вопроса, а именно - "возможно ли это реализовать" и "бесплатно ли". когда-то делал подобное под заказчика. если мой ответ вас устраивает, то пометьте мой ответ как лучший, если нет - задавайте конкретные  уточняющие комментарии.

Comment: Возможно ли это реализовать с помощью яндекс-карт?
МОжно ли хранить эти карты оффлайн?

Comment: в свое время я реализовал систему веб-мониторинга за автотранспортом - работает до сих пор на гуглах и яндексах. Яндекс Мапс АПИ считаю более удачным, чем гугловский. Более просто реализуется геокодирование, посторения маршрутов, наложения. В оффлайн это засунуть - простыми путями не получится.